# Spring Boot Eureka - CSS does not show up on a Kubernetes / Ingress

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

I am running Spring Boot Eureka on AKS (Azure Kubernetes) with a ingress to the the Eureka POD, there is no issue in loading the UI but the CSS and the wor.js does not load.

application.properties

```java
eureka:
  dashboard:
    enabled: true
    path: /webui
```

Ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: discovery-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /discovery(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
         serviceName: discovery
         servicePort: 8761
```

I am new to Ingress so trying to figure out how to map the:

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="eureka/css/wro.css">
```

and the

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="eureka/js/wro.js" ></script>
```

so that he default ingress backend does not give a 404.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically Ingress gives you an external endpoint like `eureka.example.com` so your javascript should be loaded in the form of `https://eureka.example.com/js/wro.js`

Also please use https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes so that spring-cloud and Kubernetes do not step on each other toes.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot, we will rewire our services.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: @runnercoder how did you solve that issue. my eureka server css doesnt work, I cannot change the css path which is included eureka

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48256365/3514300 try this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I'm hosting my eureka server with Nginx, the following config solved this issue.

```
  location /eureka/ {
    proxy_pass          http://localhost:8761/eureka/;
    proxy_redirect      http://localhost:8761/eureka/ https://example.com;
  }
```